# Intent Redirection If The Activity Is Exported

Tags: java, android, security

What are the security implications of an Android app that exports an activity and accepts a parcelable intent as an extra to start a service? Specifically, in the code sample provided below, how can this vulnerability be exploited to redirect intents and start arbitrary components?

```
    // ...
    handleIntentExtras(getIntent()); 
}

private void handleIntentExtras(Intent intent) {
    // ...
    Intent deeplinkIntent = (Intent) intent.getParcelableExtra("extra_deep_link_intent");
    //  ...
    if (!(deeplinkIntent == null || this.consumedDeeplinkIntent)) {
        // ...
        startService(deeplinkIntent); 
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'm afraid this is a programming question and is off-topic here. I've flagged it for migration though

Comment: If someone sends an intent to your app he can put there anything he wants. Then without any validation, your app will run this intent using YOUR app permissions(e.g. accessing your app's private files or doing anything else your app was granted permission to.)
Regarding your sample, someone can start other (non-exported) services that your app contains and send the action to be taken to them(what will happen next depends on the service's code)

Comment: @bmaciejm Does it only happen with `getParcelableExtra` method or other methods such as `getStringExtra` etc?

Comment: Depends on your implementation, if you are using the String obtained from e.g. `getStringExtra` as for example URL to load into webview, or a path to some data accessed by the content provider then yes. You need to consider all data that comes from outside of your application to any of your exported components as untrusted.